# Jquery Autocomplet get data in database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Im create pop up form add item and create jquery autocomplete
I'm already done jquery autocomplete in my form, but i want

when i write item_name 
example : Laptop

form  brands, type/seri, serial also appears

Laptop (item_name)
Dell (brands)
Dell Inspirion (Seri or Type)
1239196 (Licensi)

i Confused, because i write item name,
form brands, seri, licensi also show  value in form item name

**Screenshot**

[image: This Picture]

This is my code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function add_item()
            {


                //alert("tes");
                var content = '<div id="dialog_user_add" title="Add Data">';
                    content += '    <table width="100%">';
                    content += '        <tr>';
                    content += '            <td>Item</td>';
                    content += '            <td>:</td>';
                    content += '            <td><input  style="width:100%"type="text" name="txt_item" id="txt_item" value=""  class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>';
                    content += '        </tr>';
                    content += '        <tr>';
                    content += '            <td>Brand</td>';
                    content += '            <td>:</td>';
                    content += '            <td><input  style="width:100%"type="text" name="txt_brand" id="txt_brand" value=""  class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>';
                    content += '        </tr>';
                    content += '        <tr>';
                    content += '            <td>Type / Seri</td>';
                    content += '            <td>:</td>';
                    content += '            <td><input  style="width:100%"type="text" name="txt_seri" id="txt_seri" value=""  class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>';
                    content += '        </tr>';
                    content += '        <tr>';
                    content += '            <td>Serial Number</td>';
                    content += '            <td>:</td>';
                    content += '            <td><input  style="width:100%"type="text" name="txt_number" id="txt_number" value=""  class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>';
                    content += '        </tr>';
                    content += '</div>';

                    $("#txt_item").autocomplete("get_item.php",{
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            max: 50
        });

        $( "#txt_item" ).focusout(function() {
            data = $("#txt_item").val();
            $("#txt_brand").val(data);
            $("#txt_seri").val(data);
            $("#txt_number").val(data);
        });

                    }

</script>
```

**get_item.php**

```
<?php
require_once "conection.php";
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = "select item_name,pnx_licensing_freq,pnx_manufacturing,pnx_equipment_type from item where item_name LIKE '%$q%' limit 50 ";
    $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    // $cname = $rs['site_id']." / ".$rs['site_name']." - ".$rs['area'];
    $cname = $rs['item_name']; //item name
    $cname2 = $rs['pnx_manufacturing']; //brand
    $cname3 = $rs['pnx_licensing_freq']; //licensi
    $cname4 = $rs['pnx_equipment_type']; //type or seri
    echo "$cname\n";
    } ?>
```

Help me thank's :)

Comment: console.log `data` isinya apa ? object ?

Comment: saya juga masih cari gan, soalnya ini source code kantor, sebelumnya yg buat bukan saya

Comment: Ini `echo "$cname\n";` ? cuma ini yg di passing ke view? kl iy berarti `$cname2` dst ga ikut dong? dgn kt lain cm nama item yg di pass ?

Comment: iya pas di pilihan doank. tadi saya coba jadi muncul nama brand, serial sama type juga. gak ikut gan..

Comment: Ya kl gtu wajar yg muncul cuma laptop2 doang. Pertama krn yg dikirim cm `$cname = $rs['item_name'];` trs di jquery nya value buat id yg lain isinya cm ` data = $("#txt_item").val();` alias copy dr value pertama. Knp g d `json_encode` aja ?

Comment: gimana caranya gan supaya di json_encode ??

give me solution...

Comment: ealah, situ ada email? panjang2an komen dsini nti suhu2 pd ngoceh :D

Comment: ada gan nih email ane : bedhoel.com@gmail.com
makasih ya :D

Comment: Okeh, nyalain aja gchat nya

Comment: sudah gan :)
oke deh

Comment: ya...hapus aja nama lkp sy di komen ente diatas.

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
$( "#txt_item" ).focusout(function() {
        data = $("#txt_item").val();
        $("#txt_brand").val(data);
        $("#txt_seri").val(data);
        $("#txt_number").val(data);
    });
```

Copying the #txt_item value to #txt_brand #txt_seri #txt_number that's why item name autocomletes to all of them, because when you type item_name you focused  when auto complete happens.

If you don't need to copy the value of text field to other fields, just remove this function.

Comment: can you give me example ?

Comment: these lines of code: $( "#txt_item" ).focusout(function() {
            data = $("#txt_item").val();
            $("#txt_brand").val(data);
            $("#txt_seri").val(data);
            $("#txt_number").val(data);
        }); What you try do gain with them?

Comment: Yes i know, how does it so filled with a different value

give me solution